# Can't get function load jquery to work

Tags: jquery, function

I've create a two tester html files to get this working but i'm getting nothing so far.

This is the jQuery I'm using:

```
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("2.html");
});
```

This is my body:

```
<div id="header">&nbsp;</div>
```

My `2.html` contains:

```
test
```

Why won't `2.html` load into `1.html`?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Is jQuery being loaded properly? Is `2.html` accessible from the first page? Are you running via the local file system, as AJAX requests will fail in this case due to security settings. There are a million reasons why this could fail.

Comment: Do you load jQuery library first?

Comment: Is files at same level?

Comment: @Justinas Yes, I'm loading jQuery first and they're on the the same level

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ah, yes, I am testing this locally, would that be my problem then?

Comment: @SaturnsEye Most likely. You need to test on a server, either locally with IIS/LAMP/WAMP or on a remote server

Answer (score 0):

Answer found thanks to RoryMcCrossan.

I was testing the file locally and it would not work.

As soon as I hosted the file it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('2.html', function (data) {
  $('#header').html(data);
});
```

This should work fine

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your input but I've already found out that my code was fine and that I just needed to host the file for it to work.